# What's the best way to remove a single word from a quote?

Tags: quotations

I wish to quote from a source, however, the original quote contains an extra *the* that does not flow with my sentence.

Which is better, describing what the article refers to, or removing it with an ellipsis?

> It is a device, which "*assists with opening the patient’s hand [...]
>   and compensates for the [patient’s] flexor hypertonia.*"

or

> It is a device, which "*assists with opening the patient’s hand [...]
>   and compensates for ... flexor hypertonia.*"

Answer (score 2):

It is usual to indicate a word [thus] when it was *absent* in the original, but could be inferred from the context. The word is added to the quote, or replaces one, to give it sense. For example:

> After being disturbed by intruders several times we came up with a solution. We installed an infra-red detector to deter them.

The second sentence could be quoted out of its context like this:

> We installed an infra-red detector to deter [intruders].

But, if you want to omit a word or phrase from a sentence, you can use the elipisis, usually without any square brackets. So the sentence becomes

> It is a device, which "*assists with opening the patient’s hand ... and compensates for ... flexor hypertonia.*"

because you have only removed words, with none added.

Comment: Editorial ellipsis is often put in square brackets, to distinguish it from ellipsis in the source. But a style guide will often instruct on whether they are required or not.